# How do I get pip working directory from command line

Tags: python, pip

I have two python versions installed in my computer and, whenever I "pip [something]" on my command line, I would like to make sure that I am using the right pip.exe program. Is there a pip command for that?

Thank you.

Comment: You can try `which pip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip --version
```

This will give complete path of pip install

Comment: Thank you ksholla20! That's exactly what I needed. Actually, I've just noticed that I can also specify the python pip version I want to use, by doing "pip3.5", for example.

Answer (score 0):

`python` has a `-m` module option,

```
$ python --help | grep -- -m
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

So one can use it like,

```
$ python -m pip install requests
```

And it will make sure, you are using the correct `pip` for the `python` you are running.

```
( venv ) $ python -m pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /home/telaverge/python/tty/tias/a/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
( venv ) $ deactivate
$ python -m pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /home/telaverge/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Under windows, i think it is,

```
py -m pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but sorry if I am wrong! If you are on Window, when installing Python, make sure to check this box(Add Python *version* to PATH) otherwise you will have to do it manually or probably use something like this.

```
python -m pip command option
```

[image]

If you have Python added to your PATH.

You can do from command line(for example).

```
pip install packagename
```